# MongoDB merge two same schema collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongoDB with node express and I have two collection in my db having name "user" and "user_archive". I want to merge both collection data in a query and want to perform pagination.

For single collection pagination I am using below code:

```
user.find(condition)
        .select()
        .limit(perPage)
        .skip(perPage * page)
        .sort(sortObject)
        .exec(function(err, data)
        {
                callback(err,data);

        });
```

I want to perform pagination by merging both user and user_archive collection data.

user collection

```
{"name":A}
{"name": B}
```

user_archive collection

```
{"name":C}
{"name":D}
```

I need to merge both collection like below and then want to perform pagination:

```
{"name":A}
{"name":B}
{"name":C}
{"name":D}
```

Could anyone please suggest how can I do that in my code.

Comment: You can use the lookup operator in aggregation for this purpose. It's performing a left inner join, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: @TeTeT As I mention both collection have same schema and I don't want to perform join. I just need to merge data from both collection and then want to perform pagination.

Comment: this db design isn't decent, u'd better add the field "isArchived" in "users" collection. Sort+skip on multiple lists can't be done mathematically unless u join them

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation piplines.
For example

**User collection**

```
{ "_id": "1", "email": "test1@gmail.com", "fullName": "Jon1"},
{ "_id": "2", "email": "test2@gmail.com", "fullName": "Jon2"},
{ "_id": "3", "email": "test3@gmail.com", "fullName": "Jon3"}
```

**Post Collection**

```
{ "_id": "11", "owner": "1", "content": "text1"},
{ "_id": "12", "owner": "2", "content": "text2"},
{ "_id": "13", "owner": "3", "content": "text3"},
```

.

```
async function getData (options) {
let query = [];

// merge posts and users
query.push(
    { $lookup: { from: 'posts', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'owner', as: 'posts' } }
);

// pagination
if (options.page && options.size) {
    let skip = options.size * (options.page - 1);

    query.push(
        { $skip: skip },
        { $limit: options.size }
    );
}

return await db.posts.aggregate(query);
```

}

The result from this function will be

```
{ "_id": "11", "owner": { "_id": "1", "email": "test1@gmail.com", "fullName": "Jon1" }, "content": "text1"},
{ "_id": "12", "owner": { "_id": "2", "email": "test2@gmail.com", "fullName": "Jon2" }, "content": "text2"},
{ "_id": "13", "owner": { "_id": "3", "email": "test3@gmail.com", "fullName": "Jon3" }, "content": "text3"}
```

For example if options = { page: 1, size: 2 }, result will be

```
{ "_id": "11", "owner": { "_id": "1", "email": "test1@gmail.com", "fullName": "Jon1" }, "content": "text1"},
{ "_id": "12", "owner": { "_id": "2", "email": "test2@gmail.com", "fullName": "Jon2" }, "content": "text2"},
```

Comment: You can't merge 2 collections with no reference in one aggregation pipeline.